# top.window.location from within a facebook canvas app?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

There are circumstances where I'd like a link to break out of facebook canvas' iframe. For example, if I'm linking to to the apple app store, it seems more prudent to have the link target="_top" or top.window.location.

Are there any circumstances in which it is against fb policy to link out to the top window?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do this if you are setting cookies and such. When the user first visits, I capture the signed_request, and send them to a different URL via window.parent.location.

Then once they've authenticated on my domain (where I can set 1st party cookies easily), I send them back into the canvas application to a specific page.

If there's a better way I'd love to hear it.